# Contact selector not providing expected results in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-contacts

I have a fairly simple piece of code to retrieve the contact info from the picker but it is not giving me expected results.
I am getting the name of the contact but not the number. For some reason, the cursor is returning an index of -1 (The reason for the crashing application). I can ensure you that the contact has a number field filled in. I can not pinpoint the reason for this error.

```
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (requestCode == PICKCONTACT) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                val contactData = data?.data?:throw error("error")
                val cursor = contentResolver.query(contactData, null, null, null, null)
                cursor?.moveToFirst()?:throw error("Data not found")
                val phNoIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER )
                val nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME)
                Log.i("phoneNo", "$nameIndex $phNoIndex")
//                recipient.put(cursor.getString(nameIndex), cursor.getString(phNoIndex) as Int)
                phone=cursor.getString(phNoIndex)
                name=cursor.getString(nameIndex)

                cursor.close()
                Log.i("info", phone+name)

                Log.i("phone", name)
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT: I am adding the intent picker request -

```
public fun pickContact(view: View){
        val intent=Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI)
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICKCONTACT )
    }
```

The error is as follows:

```
Process: com.example.smssender, PID: 29366
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/745i7546045a8e2cb2bf.3789r1632-29294B4F39.847r1845-29294B4F39/1851 flg=0x1 (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.smssender/com.example.smssender.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4610)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4652)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1948)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
        at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
        at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:465)
        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
        at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:137)
        at com.example.smssender.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.kt:54)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7762)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4603)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4652) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1948) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

Comment: post the code in which you're launching the picker intent

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in the contact's phone number, you should be using a "phone picker" not a "contact picker".

This picker will ask the user to pick a contact > and then a phone number belonging to that contact.

Here's the code:

```
Intent intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent.setType(CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE); // Note the Phone type
startActivityForResult(intent, PICKCONTACT);
```

And here's how to get the info from the onActivityResult intent:

```
Uri dataUri = data.getData();
String[] projection = new String[]{CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(dataUri, projection, null, null, null);
```

Comment: // Note the Phone type - this is what I so long found, thank you!